# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed

Tags: java, android, system

I'm building an android app using Ionic and I have an error while trying to read .so file with System.loadLibrary method

I have plugin.xml file with `<lib-file src="src/android/libs/native-libs.jar"/>`
and this is my android plugin structure[image]

I want to load .so files inside native-libs.jar `System.loadLibrary("jniidengine")`
And this is my code inside build.gradle [image]

But I've got this error  `AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libjniidengine.so" not found`

Also I've tried to add folders from native-libs.jar inside jniLibs folder inside android/src and add to gradle `sourceSets { main { jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/jniLibs'] }` but it didn't work too.
Please help, maybe I'm missing something